# Enyim.Caching.Memcached - Failed to read from Socket

Tags: memcached, membase, enyim

I'm currently building an environment for deploying a web.application.

The Web.Application uses Enyim.Caching.
There looks to be an issues with the sockets

I'm unfamiliar with membase server, if there is any additional information that I can include in this post please ask...

Any suggestions on what I can check would be greatly appreciated:

```
 Enyim.Caching.Memcached.MemcachedNode.InternalPoolImpl - Pool has been inited for 127.0.0.1:11212 with 10 sockets`
 Enyim.Caching.Memcached.MemcachedNode.InternalPoolImpl - Acquiring stream from pool. 127.0.0.1:11212`
 Enyim.Caching.Memcached.PooledSocket - Socket 86101442-5fc2-4169-bba2-9f25f1647254 was reset
 Enyim.Caching.Memcached.MemcachedNode.InternalPoolImpl - Socket was reset. 86101442-5fc2-4169-bba2-f25f1647254
 Enyim.Caching.Memcached.MemcachedNode - System.IO.IOException: Failed to read from the socket '127.0.0.1:11212'. Error: ?
     at Enyim.Caching.Memcached.PooledSocket.BasicNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) in d:\d\repo\EnyimMemcached\Enyim.Caching\Memcached\BasicNetworkStream.cs:line 92
     at System.IO.BufferedStream.ReadByte()
     at Enyim.Caching.Memcached.PooledSocket.ReadByte() in
```

Answer (score 0):

Enyim uses port **11211** by default.  It looks like you are trying **11212** instead, try changing to 11211.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was happening because we were trying to store and read an object that was too large.  Even after increasing memory, the problem remained.  I'm not sure exactly what "too large" is in this context, but definitely memcached bottomed out when a particularly large amount of data was being stored in it.